# how to get the sum of the rows before the current row in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL query that computes partial sums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583464/mysql-query-that-computes-partial-sums)

ok, the question is not clear at all so the example would be:
i have a table like this:

```
id     amount

1       1000
2       2500
3       5000
```

and i need to select from it the following data:

```
id     oamount     total

1       1000      1000
2       2500      3500
3       5000      8500
```

i tried this but it is not correct:

```
    select *,sum(oamount) from `table` 
group by id;
```

and i can't figure it out

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've answered a very similar where they were trying to get cash flow balances for beginning / ending of each day...  [Found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812696/increasing-mysql-query-performance-math-heavy-query/8813471#8813471)

Yours would be very similar... Prequery the data in the final order you want it (ie: starting ID would be the first of the result set), then apply what you want with MySQL Variables

```
select
      PreAgg.ID,
      PreAgg.Amount,
      @PrevBal := @PrevBal + PreAgg.Amount as Total
   from 
      ( select
              YT.id,
              YT.amount
           from
              YourTable YT
           order by
              YT.id ) as PreAgg,
      ( select @PrevBal := 0.00 ) as SqlVars
```

I've actually kept the pre-aggregate as a query... in case you wanted to actually DO some aggregations like based on transactions on a daily basis, or applied some other WHERE clause.  This would allow flexibility to ensure your final output order was prepared BEFORE starting your @PrevBal accumulation.

Comment: I was thinking about some PL/SQL with cursor and loop, but this is cool ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
select 
  *,
  (select sum(oamount) from `table` WHERE id <= t.Id) AS total
from `table` AS t
```

Comment: replace < with <= and pray for ids to be unique :)

Comment: Although it could work, depending on the size of the data, could become painful,  5 record would have to count 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 instances in the subquery... try that again with 1000 entries...

Comment: @DRapp Yep, performance killer. Its a fast'n'simple decision. Performance-effective will be slightly different

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT id,amount,@total := @total + amount 
 FROM `table`, (SELECT @total := 0) as dummy 
 ORDER BY id;
```

Note that this doesn't work when using GROUP BY clauses / aggregates.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SET @res:=0;
SELECT
   t.a,
   t.b,
   (@res := @res + t.b) AS summ
FROM
(SELECT first AS a, second AS b FROM table GROUP BY a ORDER BY a) AS t
```